# Research on building associations through sensory cues for practical applications in the literature

Tags: reference-request

I recently came across an episode of *Crowd Control* where the showrunners placed distinct visual, aural, and olfactory clues in zones of a parking lot to assist individuals in locating their cars more easily ([Link](https://www.dailymotion.com/video/x6q3211) - 18:39). What are some works related to this experiment in the psychology/neuroscience literature? What I'm looking for is:

1. Specific instances in the psychology/neuroscience literature where researchers attempt to build certain associations in subjects' minds by placing sensory cues
2. Putting these associations to work in some useful way - e.g. the carpark example